# VanillaJS Promise implementation to replace jQuery notify/progress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I am currently using a `$.Deferred()` object for posting messages.

When the server returns an error, I am using `notify`, and try again until it succeeds or fails `X` times.

I want to remove the usage of jQuery, ant move to ES6 related options.

I know how to use `Promise()`, but it can either be rejected or resolved, but not both.

Is there a better idea?

The current code:

```
var def = $.Deferred(),
  data = {
    iTries: 0,
    ....
  };

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "POST",
  data: data,
  timeout: 15000,
  success: d => def.resolve(d);,
  error: function(vSocket, status, error) {
    def.notify('error'); // this I want to replace
    data.iTries++;

    //try again
    if (data.iTries < 40) window.setTimeout(function() {
      DoAgain(data, def).then(q => def.resolve(q));
    }, 9000);
    else {
      def.reject();
    }
  }
  else {
    if (data.iTries < 20) window.setTimeout(function() {
      Poll.AjaxPoll(data, def).then(q => def.resolve(q));
    }, 30000);
  }
}
});
```

Comment: `$.Deferred` has basically nothing to do with [tag:es6-promise], although it's been retrofitted to not actually be incompatible with promises anymore. If you're using ES2015+ code (and you are -- arrow functions, for instance), use `Promise`, not `$.Deferred`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your code that you are using ES6 (you are using arrow functions). You can follow a recursive approach with es6 arrow functions and promises, it could be something like this:

```
doAjaxRequest(data) {
    fireAPICall(data).then(response => { // fireAPICall is a method that fires the post request and returns the response received from server
        if(response.status == 200) { // success (this if statement is optional)
            // handle success
            let d = response.data;
        }
    }).catch(error => { // failure
        data.iTries++;
        if(data.iTries < 40) {
            window.setTimeout(() => {doAjaxRequest(data)}, 9000); // try again
        } else if(data.iTries < 20) {
            window.setTimeout(() => {doAjaxRequest(data)}, 30000); // try again
        }
    });
}
```

For the `fireAPICall` method, you can use any promise-based http client like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), here I'm using `axios`:

```
fireAPICall(data) {
    return axios.post("url", data);
}
```

**Update**: if you want handle both `reject/failure` event and `notify/progress` events, this will need some server-side collaboration. You could make your server return a `202` status code (or any other more appropriate status code) in case of progress event (not ready yet) and you can handle that in your `.then()` callback:

```
doAjaxRequest(data) {
    fireAPICall(data).then(response => { // fireAPICall is a method that fires the post request and returns the response received from server
        if(response.status === 202) { // notify/progress event
            data.iTries++;
            if(data.iTries < 40) {
                window.setTimeout(() => {doAjaxRequest(data)}, 9000); // try again
            } else if(data.iTries < 20) {
                window.setTimeout(() => {doAjaxRequest(data)}, 30000); // try again
            } else {
                return Promise.reject('poll eneded with no success'); // exceeded maximum number of times for polling, so reject. This will invoke the catch callback method with this error
            }
        } else { // handle success
            let d = response.data;
        }
    }).catch(error => { // reject/failure for some other reason
        // handle error
    });
}
```

Comment: this is what I was done, but I want to update  the  parent code that something wrong, like WhatsApp `clock` state (sent was failed, wait).

Comment: @MosheL I can't get you, do you mean you want to wait for sometime before firing a new request in case of a specific error? Or you want to remove the usage of jQuery at all and just use es6 promises?

Comment: I have a  problem with `progress` event. I can use your example with axios or fetch api for request, but If the request failed for server-reason I want to notify (not `reject`!) and try again.

Comment: I think this will need some collaboration from the server side. For example, in case of progress you could make your server side return a specific `status code` like `202`. Another alternative is to let your server return a response body containing a property (say `status`) with `0` for progress, `1` for success, `2` for failure or any values you want to indicate the status and you can check for it in your `.then()` callback and let the `catch()` for server errors as you say (`reject`).

Comment: But remember, if you use `202` status code then you will need to handle the progress event inside the `.then()` callback as 202 is not an error code. Also most probably for the other approach you would return a non-error status code which will also need to be handled in `.then()` callback and let the `.catch()` for error codes.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, a promise can only be settled **once**. (This is also true of jQuery's `$.Deferred`, which is [now] mostly promise-like.)

Recurring notifications aren't a use case for promises. Instead, you want some kind of event emitter or publish/subscribe system (there are same **extremely** small ones for jQuery, such as [this one](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub) [not an endorsement]), or even just a callback you call with progress updates.

Comment: @MosheL - There are plenty of pub/sub libs that don't rely on jQuery. At heart, after all, pub/sub is **really** simple.